# Want to post to options.php and call a custom function with Ajax, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Right now when I update my plugin page the settings save and does what I want besides calling my action hook, test handler. Overall, the ajax request seems to be working and adding my options to the database but not calling my test handler function. Is it possible to post to the options.php and call a custom function to perform a few more things?

Here is my jQuery code that submits the form data to WordPress options.php

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#yacht-form').on( 'submit', function(event) {

        console.log($("input#submit").attr("disabled","disabled"));

        var ylocations = $('#ylocations').val();

        if (ylocations == 0) {
            $('.button-save').html('<p>Error! Empty Value.</p>').show().fadeIn();
            $('.button-save').addClass('button-error');
            $('.button-save').delay(5000).fadeOut();
            $("input#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            return false;
        }

        var settings =  $(this).serialize();
        console.log(settings);
        // submit the data


        $.post( 'options.php', settings, { action: 'test_handler'} ).error( 
                function() {
                    alert('error');
                }).success( function() {

                    $('.button-save').html('<p>Changes Saved!</p>').show().fadeIn();
                    $('.button-save').delay(3000).fadeOut();


                });
                $("input#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                return false;

    });

});
```

Here is the code I am calling the action

```
function test_handler() {
    $post_arr = array(
        'post_title'   => 'Test post',
        'post_content' => 'Test post content',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'tax_input'    => array(
            'hierarchical_tax'     => $hierarchical_tax,
            'non_hierarchical_tax' => $non_hierarchical_tax,
        ),
        'meta_input'   => array(
            'test_meta_key' => 'value of test_meta_key',
        ),
    );
    wp_insert_post($post_arr);

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test_handler', 'test_handler' );
```

Comment: Is the page refreshing? You may need to `return false;` or call `event.preventDefault();` to stop the form from submitting. The submit event handler doesn't stop the form from submitting and the ajax call is sent out asynchronously so that doesn't block the script to wait for a response.

Comment: My page doesn't reload on submit and even when I add preventDefault I still get no response from my function.

Comment: So you're on the options page, hitting submit, and the option gets saved or updated? Looks like the form is submitting the normal ajax way and your .post function isn't doing anything. You need to use the ajax url, not options.php, to get to the handler function. Search for `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` on this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and see if that helps.